# android kernel for ascend mate with linker error

Tags: android, gcc, linker, kernel

I made a port from a kernel from 4.1 to 4.4, but I get this errors, I know that this error is by the linker, but I have no idea about where find the error because these files are already compiled, sorry for my bad english, this is the comand and the result in the terminal, thanks in advance:

```
richy@richy-Aspire-V5-572P:~/Lollipop/kernel/mt_4.4$ make -k ARCH=arm zImage
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  GEN     .version
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux1
drivers/built-in.o:felica_gpio.c:function felica_remove: warning: relocation refers to discarded section
drivers/built-in.o:felica_gpio.c:function felica_remove: warning: relocation refers to discarded section
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:iomux.c:function get_active_block_table.part.0: error: undefined reference to 'g_current_board_id'
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:k3v2_clocks_init_data_cs_60M.c:function iomux_debug_show: error: undefined reference to 'g_current_board_id'
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:k3v2_clocks_init_data_cs_60M.c:function iomux_debug_set: error: undefined reference to 'g_current_board_id'
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:k3v2_clocks_init_data_cs_60M.c:function pmulowpower: error: undefined reference to 'get_battery_removable'
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:k3v2_clocks_init_data_cs_60M.c:function pmulowpower: error: undefined reference to 'get_battery_removable'
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:k3v2_clocks_init_data_cs_60M.c:function pmulowpowerall: error: undefined reference to 'get_battery_removable'
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:k3v2_clocks_init_data_cs_60M.c:function pmulowpowerall: error: undefined reference to 'get_battery_removable'
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:board-k3v2oem1.c:wl18xx_device: error: undefined reference to 'wilink_pdata'
drivers/built-in.o:mipi_jdi_OTM1282B.c:function mipi_jdi_panel_off: error: undefined reference to 'rmi_f01_glove_switch_read'
drivers/built-in.o:mipi_jdi_OTM1282B.c:function mipi_jdi_panel_off: error: undefined reference to 'rmi_fc'
drivers/built-in.o:es305.c:function es305_set_pathid: error: undefined reference to 'is_smartpa_support'
drivers/built-in.o:synaptics_SO340010.c:function synaptics_thread_irq_handler: error: undefined reference to 'time_finger_up'
drivers/built-in.o:synaptics_SO340010.c:function synaptics_thread_irq_handler: error: undefined reference to 'touch_is_pressed'
drivers/built-in.o:felica_gpio.c:function felica_remove: warning: relocation refers to discarded section
drivers/built-in.o:modemctl.c:function modemctl_init: error: undefined reference to 'is_modem_switch_support'
drivers/built-in.o:mipi_jdi_OTM1282B.c:function jdi_probe: error: undefined reference to 'get_touchkey_enable'
drivers/built-in.o:hi6421-regulator.c:function hi6421_regulator_probe: error: undefined reference to 'get_pmu_out26m_enable'
drivers/built-in.o:synaptics_SO340010.c:function touchkey_probe: error: undefined reference to 'get_touchkey_enable'
Makefile:907: recipe for target '.tmp_vmlinux1' failed
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
make: Target 'zImage' not remade because of errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere about this and I fix it, just I've added the definition of these variables or functions, cause the "extern"s don't works for itselfs, i.e.

for the line:

```
arch/arm/mach-k3v2/built-in.o:iomux.c:function get_active_block_table.part.0: error: undefined reference to 'g_current_board_id'
```

just is add to the file iomux.c the global
"type" g_current_board_id;

or in the case of functions:
"type" functionname(type args) {}

and that is all